# Immediate request after response

Tags: wicket

First, what I want to achieve:
Let's say I'm doing some stuff in onClick() method of a AjaxLink. I want to give user some feedback with mid-status and continue on doing, and give another feedback.

To do this I thought of adding some component, or behaviour that would send ajax request immediately after being rendered onto page so that I could continue in onEvent() of this behaviour. How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out myself. It is enough to add such implementation of `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior`:

```
new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() {
    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        response.renderOnLoadJavascript(getCallbackScript().toString());
    }
}
```

`respond(AjaxRequestTarget target)` will be invoked when component it was added to is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you noted can likely lead to a solution, but a common approach for giving continuing updates is to use an [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html), as in this simple [clock example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/clock).

Comment: I was thinking about this, but after code analysis I realized that request would be done even after calling stop() function, only that onTimer() would not be invoked